# python 3.7.0 mypy 0.641 extending pythons' list with UserList?

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I am trying to extend pythons’ `list` with some custom methods, for that I
am creating an class inheriting from `UserList`.

I am not sure what is the right way and I would like to get `mypy` play
nicely with `UserList`.

I consulted [cpython UserList docs](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ffef50f1f5907e5f0f175b12088d3e509011f126/Doc/library/collections.rst#L1155-L1193) and searched inside `mypy` for
`UserList` but couldn’t find anything.

Using:

- mypy 0.641
- python 3.7.0

This is a minimal example of what I am trying to achive

```
from collections import UserList
from typing import List, Optional, Union


class A:
    ...


class B:
    ...


class C:
    ...


TMessage = Union[A, B, C]


class MyList(UserList):
    """Minimal example"""

    def __init__(self, data: Optional[List[TMessage]] = None) -> None:
        self.data: List[TMessage] = []
        if data:
            self.data = data[:]

    def get_last(self) -> TMessage:
        return self.data[-1]

    # other methods to be added ...


some_data = [A(), B(), C(), C(), B(), A()]
my_list_a = MyList(some_data)
my_list_b = MyList(some_data)

my_list_b = my_list_a[3:]
```

Mypy complains as follows

```
~/tmp ❯❯❯ mypy mypy_userlist.py

mypy_userlist.py:34: error: Argument 1 to "MyList" has incompatible type "List[object]"; expected "Optional[List[Union[A, B, C]]]"
mypy_userlist.py:35: error: Argument 1 to "MyList" has incompatible type "List[object]"; expected "Optional[List[Union[A, B, C]]]"
mypy_userlist.py:37: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "MutableSequence[Any]", variable has type "MyList")
```

I could add `# type: ignore` to the conflicting lines but I would like
to avoid that.

What is the right way to extend the python’s list with custom methods
and get mypy happy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly new at MyPy but I think you have two issues. The first is that lists are mutable, so although your list object `some_data` satisfies the required structure in your code, there's no reason that an object, not of type `A`, `B` or `C` couldn't be added to it later, meaning at compile tile, Mypy can't ensure that

```
my_list_a = MyList(some_data)
```

is a valid assignment. (have a look at the common issues section of the Mypy docs [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#invariance-vs-covariance) for more discussion)

You can fix this by explicitly annotating `some_data`:

```
some_data : List[TMessage] = [A(), B(), C(), C(), B(), A()]
```

The second problem will pop up when you fix this, when you try and assign your two lists using slicing. MyPy won't know what your slice function will return and will complain about incompatible types.

To fix this, you can explicitly implement the slice functionality into your class.

```
def __getitem__(self, slice_indices) -> 'MyList':
     return self.data[slice_indices]
```

Comment: That helps, thanks! My motivation to extend from `UserList` was to avoid having to redifine methods like `__getitem__ __setitem__` (In my example I already had to define `__init__` which I also wanted to avoid). If in the end if have to reimplement them, I don't see a point on inheriting from `UserList`. Maybe I should just implement my ow class and define the typings I need and forget about extending from `UserList`.

Comment: Glad I could help. I've tried experimenting but I can't find a way to make MyPy happy without implementing some of these functions at least. It does save you having to implement `append` etc and lets you input `MyList` into functions requiring list inputs, so there are advantages of the inheritance.